# Hibernate creates a SQL query

Tags: sql, hibernate

Hibernate creates a SQL query looking for data from a database.table and SQL wants the request to be from [database.table]. how do I get Hibernate to put in the [ ]?

Comment: What do you mean with "SQL wants"? Do you mean "SQL **Server**" wants that format? Because in "*SQL*" `[` and `]` are invalid for object names.

Answer (score 2):

The need for quoting database identifiers derives from the database used, some do, some don't; it is not SQL per se that "wants" this. So you need to set the correct database dialect then Hibernate will do this automatically if needed. In fact it is one of the benefits of Hibernate that you don't need to care for this differences.